# Angular2 - Dynamically loading Ace editor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am trying to load ace editor dynamically into my angular2 application at the click of a button but it looks like that ace editor is producing the following error on console:

> Error: ace.edit can't find div #editor

Here is an example code:

**main.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `<div [innerHTML]="html" ></div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addAce()" >Add Ace</button>`
})
class MainApp{

  public html = "";

  constructor(){}

  addAce(){

    this.html = "<pre style='height:100vh' id='editor' ></pre>";

    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
  }
}
bootstrap(MainApp);
```

I want this code to work exactly in this position. Why ace editor can't find the id that I am giving to pre tag? I can see `editor` id in the source code after bootstrapping the app. I re-produced the problem [here on plunkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/oCA0IuvRxw603hRDqWMS/). You can monitor the console for the error message. Thanks in anticipation.

**Update**

I tried doing it this way

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addAce()" >Add Ace</button>
  <div><pre style='height:100vh' id='editor' ></pre></div>`
})
class MainApp{
  public aceId = "";

  constructor(){}

  addAce(){

    this.aceId = "editor";

    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
  }
}
bootstrap(MainApp);
```

but still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was playing along I thought may be ace editor is too quick to check the id before angular 2 manipulates the DOM :P. So I tried the setTimeout function and tried creating ace editor inside setTimeout callback function and guess what? it worked. Here is the working code

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addAce()" >Add Ace</button>
  <div><pre style="height:100vh;" [id]="aceId" ></pre></div>`
})
class MainApp{
  public aceId = "";

  constructor(){}

  addAce(){

    this.aceId = "editor";

    setTimeout(function(){
      var editor = ace.edit("editor");
      editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
      editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
    },0);
  }
}
bootstrap(MainApp);
```

and [here is plunkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/noGPww74QPJKZH0NDTHL/)

Comment: Doesn't feel like an optimal solution though, since it might take longer than 100ms sometimes.

Comment: Yeah I know but right now its seems the only way. Waiting for other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be problematic because you did not have the HTML done right, it is expecting a div with an ID of `editor`, like this:

```
 <div id="editor" ace-editor [(text)]="text" style="height:150px;">
```